# Which, in x86, is more efficient? Using a variable or lea of the variable?

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, x86

I have a section of x86 code inside of some c++ code:

```
void encrypt_chars (int lengthW, char EKey)
{
    __asm {                                     //
            xor esi, esi                        //zeroise esi
            mov edi, lengthW                    //store the max loop counter in a register
    for:     
            movzx  ecx, OChars[esi]             //store the character to encrypt

            lea    eax, EKey                    //by ref

            movzx   ebx, byte ptr[eax]          //store the EKey value in EBX as a keep safe for when the original is changed later 
            sub     ecx, 0x0A                   //change the current characters hex value by -10 (denary)
            and     byte ptr[eax], 0xAA         //and EKey with 170(denary) to get an encryption value
            not     byte ptr[eax]               //not the encryption value to obtain a different value
            movzx   edx, byte ptr[eax]          //store the encryption value in EDX
            or      ebx, 0xAA                   //create a second encryption value
            add     bl, dl                      //add the values in the last 8 bits of EBX and EDX (the two encryption values), store them in the last 8 bits of EBX (ignores the 9th bit from carry)
            xor     ecx, ebx                    //encrypt the original letter with the encryption value
            rol     cl, 2                       //futher encryption through rotating last 8 bits of EAX bits 2 to left

            mov    EChars[esi], cl              //move 

            inc    esi                          //increment loop counter
            cmp    esi, edi                     //compare loop counter and the max number of loops
            jl     for                          //jump if esi is less than the loop counter

    }

return;
}
```

My question is, which is more efficient, to use the lea into eax then use a pointer, or use the variable itself instead of all of the byte ptr[eax].
I know that lea is a very quick instruction, but I'm unsure as to whether referencing it in memory is more efficient than just using the variable.

Comment: Why don't you run the code a few thousand times, time it and see which way works faster?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a free benchmark generator.

Comment: Hint: loading the value into a register and keeping it there is probably the fastest, but you didn't list that as an option ;)

Comment: Write the code in C++.  Turn up optimization on "most efficient".  Compile and print out the assembly language for the function.  Compare to your version.

Comment: Hint:  The `eax` register is available for reuse after the `movzx   ebx, byte ptr[eax]` instruction.

Comment: The only way to know it is to try it...

Comment: As the comments above demonstrate there are so many things that are inefficient about this code that its going to make little difference either way. Since this is just a homework assignment designed by someone who apparently doesn't know how to program in assembly very well, I wouldn't worry about optimizing it.

Answer (score 1):

Using some register, not necessary `eax`, is better when you have multiply accesses to the given variable and the variable is global - i.e. addressed by absolute address.

In the code from the question, the variables are function arguments and they are pointed by the `ESP` or by `EBP` (depending on the compiler). So, it is the same as using EAX.

So, using the variables by name will spare one instruction (`lea eax, EKey`) from the inner loop and the code will be a little bit faster.

Notice how using inline assembly makes the code less readable and more obscure, because of the hidden code generated by the compiler. Better write everything in assembly language and then link the compiled object file to your C program.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that most of this code is performing 8 bit operations, and if the key is 8 bits, why not just load it into al? You could also get rid of the offsets for a slight improvement in speed.

```
    __asm {
            lea esi, Ochars
            mov edi, lengthW
            add edi, esi
            mov al, Ekey
    for:     
            mov cl, [esi]
            mov bl, al
            sub cl, 0x0a
            ...
```